# U=X.Y function. MRS equation

Tags: linear-algebra

A low income household has a monthly income of 900, and is qualified to receive certain welfare from government in housing.

This household has the following utility function and faces the following market information:

$U = X.Y$ where $X$ is the housing consumption (sq.) while $Y$ represents all other goods; Price of $X$ (housing per square foot) is \$0.5, and price of $Y$ (all other goods) is normalized to be \$1. Hint: MRS = $Y/X$

1. What will be the consumption bundle for this household when no subsides or welfare is offered? (hint: utility maximization given the budget constrain)

Comment: Welcome to Math Stackexchange. "Solve this for me"-questions are not well perceived on this site. Please edit your question and provide information on how this problem came up and how you have attempted to solve it so far. You can read more on how to ask a good question [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question)

Comment: This is the text of your homework, without any accompanying sentence...